# Routing in Symfony 1.4: Is there a way to allow sf_method = OPTIONS for preflight HTTP requests

Tags: symfony1, httprequest, symfony-1.4, http-verbs, preflight

you all might know that browsers do preflighted HTTP requests in some cases: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

My web application is still on Symfony1. I want to implement a RESTful service and therefore using Symfony routing to allow specific HTTP request methods like GET or POST (http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/10-Routing#chapter_10_sub_sf_method).

Example:

```
login:
  url:   /v1/login
  class: sfRequestRoute
  param: { module: rest, action: login }
  requirements:
    sf_method: [post, put, delete]
    #sf_method: [options] NOT WORKING
```

It seems to me that OPTIONS requests cannot be defined/handled as sf_method value. Because I couldn't find any information if my idea is right, I'm wondering if I'm right or maybe there is a solution I couldn't find, too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to revive this old question but I found a solution.  I ran into the same issue and I added the request method `OPTIONS` to the allowed methods in `lib/sfRequest.class.php` and `lib/sfWebRequest.class.php`  You can check the latest commit here to see the differences: [6ad018c](https://github.com/diem-project/symfony/commit/6ad018c37814146cd83a926cd1c48f2474cfb2e9)

Since I cannot update the original Symfony1 GitHub repository, I created a copy with additional fixes needed due to the various PHP upgrades.  This fixes the PHP deprecated warnings due to use of the `/e` modifier in preg_replace calls as well.
Note that this still doesn't make Symfony1 PHP7 compatible.  I'm running this successfully with PHP 5.6.30

The repository is https://github.com/diem-project/symfony.git

Background: [Diem](http://diem-project.org) uses Symfony1 (1.4.20), hence the GitHub organisation [diem-project](https://github.com/diem-project)